# Cuda Matrix multiplication program can't pass, very strange error code

Tags: c, cuda

I am doing a matrix multiplication using cuda. I think I am about to success, but some very strange error stops me, I can't find out where the code goes wrong. Below is the code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16;
__global__ void matmulKernel(float* mat_in1,float* mat_in2, float* mat_out,int mat_dim);

int main()  {
    float *h_M, *h_N, *h_P, *d_M, *d_N, *d_P;
    int i,width=10;
    int size=width*width*sizeof(float);

    dim3 block_dim(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE,1);
    int grid_size=width/BLOCK_SIZE;
    if(width%BLOCK_SIZE) grid_size++;
    dim3 grid_dim (grid_size,grid_size,1);

    h_M=(float*)malloc(size);
    h_N=(float*)malloc(size);
    h_P=(float*)malloc(size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_M,size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_N,size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_P,size);

    if(h_M==0||h_N==0||h_P==0||d_M==0||d_N==0||d_P==0)  {
        printf("memory locate fail!\n");
    }

    for(i=0;i<width*width;i++)  {
        h_M[i]=1.2*i;
        h_N[i]=1.4*i;
    }

    cudaMemcpy(d_M,h_M,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_N,h_N,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    matmulKernel<<<grid_dim,block_dim>>>(d_M,d_N,d_P,width);

    cudaMemcpy(h_P,d_P,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("firt row of the results matrix P:\n");
    for(i=0;i<width;i++)    {
        printf("%f,  %f",h_P[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

__global__ void matmulKernel(float* mat1,float* mat2, float* matP,int dim)  {
    int thread_x,thread_y,i;
    thread_x=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    thread_y=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    if(thread_x<dim&&thread_y<dim)  {
        float P_value=0.;
        for(i=0;i<dim;i++)  {
            P_value+=mat1[thread_y*dim+i]*mat2[i*dim+thread_x];
        }
        matP[thread_y*dim+thread_x]=P_value;
    }
}
```

Using nvcc compile, the error is :

```
matmul.cu(11): error: expected a ")"

matmul.cu(11): error: expected an expression

matmul.cu(11): error: expected an expression

matmul.cu(13): error: expected a ")"
```

I cannot see why the compiler report this error, anyone please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: @Jayesh this is the cuda defaul data struct type dim3.

Comment: `BLOCK_SIZE` is the problem. I see a tutorial on the C preprocessor in your near future....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a stray semicolon.

Change:

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16;
```

to:

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16
```